# Search for all *.foo files at their point of check-in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible within either Visual Studio, or on visualstudio.com to perform the following search:

- For a given solution, find all files
- With file extension ".foo"
- Across all branches/merges/checkins between Date X and Date Y

The reason is that I TFS-branched a project (then re-branched, etc.), did a ton of work and merged at the end of each sprint.  Now I need to find all ".foo" files at the point of their check-in, if they still existed at that point in time.

I have successfully managed to locate the files locally by searching the solution directory and all (project) subfolders.  This did find the files, but I was hoping to do it in a smarter way, as I know that local files will be removed when the branch is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Within Visual Studio Team Services, you can use the [Code Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search) extension. The only thing you can't filter on is date/time.

Comment: Thanks.  That's not a bad start.  Hopefully when Microsoft add the branch filter in next month, they might also consider dates in a future build...